# Execute PE from memory 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, portable-executable

I'm trying to put into my program a PE which is 64 bit and will run from my program itself. However I only have the PE execute form of 32bit so it doesn't work with my 64bit program. Source Code :

App.rc -

`IDD_EXE1 RCDATA "User.exe"`

Resource.h -

```
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        101
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#define IDD_EXE1                      1004
#endif
#endif
```

main.h -

`#pragma once
void driver();`

driver.cpp -

```
#include "main.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

using namespace std;


void RunFromMemory(char*, char*);

char _image_[] = {
    0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, [...] 0x00, 0x00
        };


int driver(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char current_file_path[1024];
    GetModuleFileNameA(0, current_file_path, 1024); // Path to current executable.
    RunFromMemory(_image_, current_file_path);
    return 0;
}

void RunFromMemory(char* pImage, char* pPath)
{
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwHeader = 0;
    DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
    DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
    DWORD firstSection = 0;
    DWORD previousProtection = 0;
    DWORD jmpSize = 0;

`IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
CONTEXT pContext;

char* pMemory;
char* pFile;
memcpy(&IDH, pImage, sizeof(IDH));
memcpy(&INH, (void*)((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew), sizeof(INH));

dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
memset(pMemory, 0, dwImageSize);
pFile = pMemory;

dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage + IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
memcpy(Sections, (char*)(firstSection), sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) * INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

memcpy(pFile, pImage, dwHeader);

if ((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment) == 0)
{
    jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
}
else
{
    jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    jmpSize += 1;
    jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
}

pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

for (dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
{
    jmpSize = 0;
    dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
    memcpy(pFile, (char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData), dwSectionSize);

    if ((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment) == 0)
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
    }
    else
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        jmpSize += 1;
        jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    }
    pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
}


memset(&peStartUpInformation, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
memset(&peProcessInformation, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
memset(&pContext, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));

peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);
if (CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, &secAttrib, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &peStartUpInformation, &peProcessInformation))
{
    pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);
    VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), dwImageSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &previousProtection);
    WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), pMemory, dwImageSize, &dwWritten);
    WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)pContext.Rbx + 8), &INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 4, &dwWritten);
    pContext.Rax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread, &pContext);
    VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess, (void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), dwImageSize, previousProtection, 0);
    ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
}
free(pMemory);
```

}`

In app.rc it has an error and in driver.cpp the error is mostly on pPath.

Comment: PE files have import tables that need to be 'fixed' by loading the DLLs they refer to, and adjusting the pointers there. Also, typically, a DLL is relocatable so you could place it anywhere in free memory and then adjust its imports and internal references. Main executables are typically not, so no relocation table is present. Then, the memory pages where a PE image starts needs to have the executable attribute set and be properly aligned. Last, but not least, even if you do all that, most anti-virus programs will detect 'suspicious behavior' and delete your program.

Comment: (continued) If you really have to do this, then your best bet, apart from very deep hacking, is to attempt to write it to a file and let windows run it via a command like `system`. However, windows itself has some degree of protection against this and, again, anti-virus will still detect the suspicious activity.

Comment: @DNT "typically, a DLL is relocatable ... executables are typically not". I disagree. These days a lot of executables are built as PIE (Position Independent Executable) as that's a requirement for taking advantage of ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization), which is a security feature many programs want.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is why I said 'typically' and not 'always' :)